# Does the ouath verifier token remain unique for every request

Tags: python, twitter, flask, tweepy

I am trying to make an application to sign in user using twitter.

I want to identify the users that have at some point in the past already logged in the application so I save the oauth verifier token received at the call back in the database and every time I am logging in a user I match the verifier that I receive at the call back if I have a token for this particular user and then fetch the access token and access token secret from the database.
courtesy [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683047/should-the-access-token-in-oauth-be-generated-every-time-the-user-logs-in?rq=1) post

This is the code I am using:

Please let me know if there is anything wrong with this, I am already confused why is the code breaking.

```
verifier= request.args['oauth_verifier']            
this_user = user_exists(verifier) #checks if a user is returned for the verification token
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
if this_user is None:
auth, error = authenticate_user(auth) #handles the oauth        
clean_up(auth) #saves in db and logs in the user
else:
try:
    auth.set_access_token(this_user[access_token], this_user[access_token_secret])
    clean_up(auth)
except tweepy.TweepError:
    auth, error = authenticate_user(auth)       
    if type(error) is None:
        clean_up(auth)
    else:
        flash('Oops! That shouldn\'t have happened! ):')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

return redirect(url_for('profile'))
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks! (: