# Google OAuth 2.0 - User needs to re-consent on EVERY refresh?

Tags: php, json, youtube-api, google-oauth

I've been creating a little script to grab YouTube monthly views from a user's YouTube channel. This script works fine but every time they refresh the page they have to reconsent access. I'd prefer for this to go away but i can't find a solution online.

I've had a look at refresh tokens but even when i add them on a refresh the users still has to re-request to get the data again, maybe it's something to do with creating a user session or storing a cookie?

Here's my current working script

```
if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
    // try to get an access token
    $code = $_GET['code'];
    $url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
    // this will be our POST data to send back to the OAuth server in exchange
    // for an access token
    $params = array(
        "code" => $code,
        "client_id" => $oauth2_client_id,
        "client_secret" => $oauth2_secret,
        "redirect_uri" => $oauth2_redirect,
        "grant_type" => "authorization_code"
    );

    // build a new HTTP POST request
    $request = new HttpPost($url);
    $request->setPostData($params);
    $request->send();

    // decode the incoming string as JSON
    $responseObj = json_decode($request->getHttpResponse());

$currentDate = date("Y-m-d");
    $monthBefore = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y-m')." -1 month"));

    $views = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DMINE&start-date='.$monthBefore.'&end-date='.$currentDate.'&metrics=views&access_token='.$responseObj->access_token);

    $json = json_decode($views);
}

$monthlyViews = $json->rows[0][0];
var_dump($monthlyViews);
```

Comment: You don't need to regenerate the token each time, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683047/should-the-access-token-in-oauth-be-generated-every-time-the-user-logs-in

Comment: I would really recommend using the google oauth PHP SDK rather than you trying to do it on your own. https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client